# How to install ssh certificate on >400 servers?

Tags: windows, ssh, mingw

To not type password when doing anything on any of these servers, I need to upload my ssh certificate to the remote:

`ssh-copy-id CptBartender@remote`

Now... I need to upload that cert to over 400 servers, and I'm trying to find a way not to type/paste my password this many times.

Question is: how can I automate this on Windows (with MinGW)? Cygwin is most likely not an option because it seems to be behind the great corpo firewall from hell.

So far I've:

1. creatd a script that would iterate over every remote, but it asks for password for every one of them
2. tried passing the password with `yes` to no avail
3. read about `expect`, but couldn't find a way to get it working on MinGW
4. read about `sshpass` - same as `expect`

I've though about `AutoIt`ing it, but there must be a better way...

Comment: It's not up to me - these servers are another department's "toys" and that, while a sane request/solution, won't get through. Passwords are synchronised via LDAP, but profiles (and by extension certificates) are not... not sure how it works internally, I'm not an admin myself.

Comment: You don't have to be confined to MinGW. ActiveState Tcl contains expect in the form of a package: http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/expect4win/?_ga=1.38288294.401690331.1461065805

Comment: Booting your machine from a clever live Linux (such as what ships with Ubuntu install) and installing expect into the in-memory OS is also and option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTY's `plink` can accept the password as a command-line parameter. It doesn't have a direct equivalent to `ssh-copy-id`, but that can be scripted easily, e.g. by running the commands manually...

```
plink foo@bar -pw baz "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo 'ssh-ed25519 AAAA...' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

...or by uploading the file with `pscp`.

---

Also, if `expect` won't work on Windows, surely you could run it on one of those 400 Linux servers?

(Also, given the numbers, maybe you should look into pulling the keys from LDAP, or using AD/Kerberos? Recent OpenSSH versions have hooks for LDAP integration without needing third-party patches anymore.)

Comment: It's a weird setup... TL;DR I can't run it from one of them. Also, I'm not an admin and have no way of changing LDAP config for them... and the current one only synchronises passwords. I'll try with `plink` and see what happens, though...

Answer (score 0):

You can look for Putty plink tool as mentioned above.
Or you can think about using one of the configuration management systems, like Puppet, Ansible or Chef in a future.
You can use any of them to add some cert to all of your servers in no time.

Looking for your server numbers I think you seriously need to think about it.
They can be used for most routine server administration tasks, including user management, file and directories management and software.

Comment: If only there was anything to those servers that dependeds on me... All these are governed by another team, thus it's completely not up to me.